# No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Me estoy empapando en el mundo del asp.net core, estoy realizando una pequeño crud pero antes de llegar a la parte de la inserción, estoy en la visualización tengo el siguiente código.

```
 public IActionResult Index()
    {
        IEnumerable<Odontologo_Controller> list_odontologo = _context.Modelo_Odontologo;
        return View(list_odontologo);
    }
```

Pero al momento de compilar me arroja el sgte error aqui

> _context.Modelo_Odontologo;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo de mi AppllicationDbContext

```
  using Dientes_Sanos_Core_MVC.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Dientes_Sanos_Core_MVC.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        private DbSet<Clase_Modelo_Odontologo> modelo_Odontologo;

        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Clase_Modelo_Odontologo> Modelo_Odontologo { get => modelo_Odontologo; set => modelo_Odontologo = value; }
    }
}
```

Y por ultimo el código de mi Clase Modelo

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Dientes_Sanos_Core_MVC.Models
{
    public class Clase_Modelo_Odontologo
    {

        #region TBL_ODONTOLOGO
        [Key]

        public int ODONT_ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string ODONT_CODIGO { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "El Nombre es Obligatorio.")]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "El {0} debe ser al menos {3} ", MinimumLength = 3)]
        [Display(Name = "Nombre")]
        public string ODONT_NOMBRE { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "El Apellido es Obligatorio.")]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "El {0} debe ser al menos {3} ", MinimumLength = 3)]
        [Display(Name = "Apellido")]
        public string ODONT_APELLIDO { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "La Especialidad es Obligatorio")]
        [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "El {0} debe ser al menos {3} ", MinimumLength = 3)]
        [Display(Name = "Especialidad")]
        public string ODONT_ESPECIALIDAD { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "La Fecha de Nacimiento es Obligatorio")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [Display(Name = "Fecha Nac.")]

        public DateTime ODONT_FEC_NAC { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string ODONT_ID_TITULO { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]        
        public DateTime ODONT_FEC_ELA { get; set; }
        
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime ODONT_FEC_ACT { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string ODONT_ESTADO { get; set; }

        #endregion

    }
}
```

La pregunta es que estoy realizando de manera errónea para que me aparezca ese error :/

De antemano agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: ¿Has revisado la documentación? Intenta con `context.Tabla.ToList()`

Comment: Por otro lado, este workshop te será de utilidad: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La propiedad `list_odontologo` es de tipo `Odontologo_Controller` pero el modelo del contexto es `Clase_Modelo_Odontologo` por lo tanto hay un choque ya que no son del mismo tipo de dato.

Cambia esta linea:

```
IEnumerable<Odontologo_Controller> list_odontologo = _context.Modelo_Odontologo.ToList(); ---> No so del mismo tipo.
```

A:

```
 IEnumerable<Clase_Modelo_Odontologo> list_odontologo = _context.Modelo_Odontologo.ToList();
```

Comment: Efectivamente estaba llamando de manera errónea , cuando debía llamar a mi modelo y no a mi controlador, gracias un abrazo campeon!.